# Does Google sometime prevent new white hat sites from ranking at all in some verticals?

Tags: ranking, google-ranking, competitors

Assuming someone wants to implement a new viagra or akai berry e-commerce website. There is a lot of competition and this site does not really bring something new, other than a new online counter to buy products at a nice price.

Assuming this site does not use any black hat techniques and that it stays with Google quality guidelines, and assuming it has no (or few) backlinks (from non-authoritative websites).

Assuming this website's pages are indexed properly in Webmaster Tool, and that no penalties are reported. No site improvements are suggested. Google crawls the site daily as reported in GWT. No robots.txt configuration issues.

Does Google sometime decide to no rank this site for any user query (for weeks), because of lack of original content? The reason I am asking this is that I am trying to understand the possible cause of a similar situation I am observing with two sites.

If so, what is the way out to start ranking for these site? If not, does it mean the cause is elsewhere for sure? Any confirmed info to get out of the maze is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not unusual for a site to rank for nothing at all for several weeks.   If you don't get inbound links of any sort, there can be no rankings at all indefinitely.

Two or three weeks after you get your first few links (even if is from another site that you own), a site will start ranking poorly (usually not page 1) for some of its targeted keywords.   If the targeted keywords are competitive, page 10+ is not uncommon.  It may rank #1 for some long tail searches (usually four word phrases with low search volume).

From there it depends on how useful the site is, how novel the content is, and how many people recommend it.  Without using any blackhat shortcuts, it has been my experince that it may take a year or two until a new site gets enough search volume to pay for its own hosting.

Comment: So if I build more links, I should get out of my misery (lol). I'll try that...

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate Content

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by original content but I assume that you either mean duplicate content or content that has been respun. Respinning and Large scale duplication of content can be classed as Black Hat. Many people mistake black hat as just back links, this is not true - it is anyway of manipulating results and due to the fact that most black haters use respun and duplicate content its safe to say that any site that has a certain % of pages that are duplicate will be punished under the daily algorithm and periodic updates just as you would expect a site that isn't offering anything new.

*Search Results are Limited, Rankings are not... read on..*

Using `viagra` as a search example is a terrible example as this is a search term that is heavily filtered and even if you had quality content it's very likely that you will never get ranked for that term due to Google treats drug search results completely different and espeically something like Viagra because its been heavily abused.

So let's say you want to rank for games, now if you look on Google type in games and then try to find the limit at the bottom (Page Limit). Each page has 10 results when not logged in and this will vary but for games your see that page 34 is the limit (will vary from country to country) this means there are only 340 search results (34x10=340). The term games is extremely competeive and trying to rank for that term your unlike to be found... This does not mean your site isn't ranked, it means your below the search limit... So for example your site could be 341th but because Google has capped this search at 340 you won't be found... and this is generally the rule for every search, some searches it may even ignore you completely for one reason or another.